# Sendgrid - dynamic addTo list creation

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I'm trying to use sendgrid to send emails from my app. To add email addresses via php, according to the sendgrid docs, you use the following:

```
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$email
->addTo("example@email.com")
```

where `addTo` is used for each email address. I would like like to generate the `addTo` list dynamically, for example I have a list of 3 emails in a php variable that I would like to send mails to:

```
$email_addresses = 'example@email1.com, example@email2.com. example@email3.com';
```

I've tried the following to echo out individual `->addTo` properties per email address however it doesn't work:

```
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$email
$string = $email_addresses;
$string = preg_replace('/\.$/', '', $string); //Remove dot at end if exists
$array = explode(', ', $string); //split string into array seperated by ', '
foreach($array as $value) //loop over values
{
     echo '->addTo("'.$value.'")<br>';
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There's a `setTos` method in sendgrid-php that handles arrays: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#settos